# How do I print out json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
   "data":{
      "uuid":"123",
      "name":"TestData",
      "alias":null,
      "created_at":"2021-03-17T11:57:29.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-03-17T12:02:16.000000Z",
      "inactive_at":null,
      "default_language":"en",
      "questions":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"application_process_rate",
            "type":"rating",
            "option_count":null,
            "option_max_choices":null,
            "custom":true,
            "order":0,
            "show_extra_comment":false,
            "comment_triggers":null
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"update_rate",
            "type":"rating",
            "option_count":null,
            "option_max_choices":null,
            "custom":false,
            "order":1,
            "show_extra_comment":false,
            "comment_triggers":null
         },
         {
            "id":204,
            "name":"process_feedbackQ119",
            "type":"rating",
            "option_count":null,
            "option_max_choices":null,
            "custom":false,
            "order":2,
            "show_extra_comment":false,
            "comment_triggers":null
         },
         {
            "id":44,
            "name":"process_overallsatisfaction",
            "type":"rating",
            "option_count":null,
            "option_max_choices":null,
            "custom":true,
            "order":3,
            "show_extra_comment":false,
            "comment_triggers":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have tried using fetch on the file and then `response.json()`. It gave me the error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
> position 0

How do i use javascript + react to get the data and print it out in a list?

Comment: The reason that error occurs is because you’re parsing HTML as JSON, with the first character being `<` as the error states. Try getting the body of the fetched page instead

Comment: Your JSON is starting with a "<". That's why you have an error. It's clearly not the JSON you have in your post.

Comment: You're most probably getting a `404` when trying to fetch the file and trying to parse the resulting html response as JSON (hence the starting `<`). Post your folder hierarchy and the code which does the fetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to read a JSON file is to require it.

```
const json = require('./data.json')
```

This will read and parse the data into a JavaScript object.
Then you can iterate `json.data.questions` however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch with `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers set to `application/json`.

```
fetch('file.json', {
  headers : { 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(jsonResponse => {
  jsonResponse.data.questions.forEach(q => console.log(q.name))
});
```